# Laravel Eloquent Model, return blank data for column based on value of another column

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have the following User model

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'company', 'mobile', 'mobile_share', 'dob', 'email', 'password', 'active'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team', 'team_user', 'team_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

When using eloquent queries, is there a way to automatically return empty `mobile` data if `mobile_share` is equal to `0` in the row?

Comment: Eloquent Mutators may be what you're looking for: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) does the job.

```
public function getMobileAttribute()
{
    if ($this->mobile_share !== 0 && isset($this->attributes['mobile'])) {
        return $this->attributes['mobile'];
    }
}
```

Then just call it easily with.

```
$user->mobile;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, all the answers should work but you can inline it ! :

```php
public function getMobileAttribute($mobile)
{
    return $this->mobile_share ? $mobile : null;
}
```

For a more detail explanation :

passing $mobile in your getter function allow to get the current `mobile` Attribute, so basically, if $this->mobile_share != 0 and is not null then return the mobile, if not, return null

Answer (score -2):

I have a solution that can fit your needs.
In your Model, define a getter:

```
public getMobileAttribute($value)
{
    if (!$this->mobile_share) {
        return null;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: this throws an exception